# What is the sentence structure uses after "that"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> The first is the plethora of small businesses, from family-run corner shops and ice-cream parlours to hardware stores, that by and large are as scruffy as they were back then, eke out a meagre existence and remain stubbornly cash-only.

We usually see , sub+ verb/ only verb after "that",but in this sentence, uses by after "that" and uses "and". How do construct this sentence? And waht is the meaning of sentence?

Comment: "by and large" is an entire phrase which functions at an adverb here. Cf. "businesses (...) that **really** are as scruffy as..."

Comment: It's the main part of the relative clause "that by and large are as scruffy as they were back then, eke out a meagre existence and remain stubbornly cash-only". The idiomatic phrase "by and large" is just an optional adjunct in the relative clause, meaning "on the whole" or "everything considered".